# Angularjs - How to push items into array based on bool values

Tags: angularjs, boolean, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in getCountryGroups()">
        {{country.name}}
</li>
```

I am trying to only display records if a bool value is true:

My controller:

```
$scope.countries = [
    {name: 'France', population: 63.1, visited: true},
    {name: 'Spain', population: 23.5, visited: true},
    {name: 'Greece', population: 44.6, visited: true},
    {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8, visited: false}
];


$scope.getCountryGroups = function () {
    var groupArrayNew = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.countries, function (item, idx) {
        if (groupArrayNew.indexOf(item.visited) == -1)
          groupArrayNew.push(item.visited)
    });

    return groupArrayNew.sort();
}
```

However nothing is displayed on the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pusing the `item.visited`  versus `item`.  You need to update your `push` and `indexOf` statements.  (see the last part of my answer because `filter` is better in your situation)

Change:

```
 groupArrayNew.push(item.visited)
```

To

```
 groupArrayNew.push(item)
```

---

```
$scope.getCountryGroups = function () {
  var groupArrayNew = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.countries, function (item, idx) {
    if (item.Visited)
      groupArrayNew.push(item)l
  });
  return groupArrayNew.sort();
}
```

You could also bypass the function and use the built in [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries|filter:{visited:true}">{{country.name}}</li>
```

[Sample plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GN0LPyICbat1oGxRvMf5?p=preview) that shows both:

Answer (score 3):

Or do it in the template:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries">
  <p ng-show="country.visited">{{country.name}}</p>
</li>
```

or (as suggested in the comments) use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:{visited:true}">
  {{country.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: doing it in template much more cleaner and asy way to do it... but if you need that array in controller that is another thing...

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$scope.getCountryGroups = function () {
    var groupArrayNew = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.countries, function (item, idx) {
        if (item.visited)
          groupArrayNew.push(item)
    });

    return groupArrayNew;
}
```

Although has been pointed out in the comments, unless you need `groupArrayNew` for other purposes (which I don't suspect you do as it is calculated each time by the function), you can achieve what you want with a filter

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:{visited:true}">
    {{country.name}}
</li>
```